# Find service promise fails in feathersJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, feathersjs

I am writing my first feathersjs app. Server side is fine, tested with postman and working perfectly. Client side I keep getting a failed promise on the 'find' service as it is out of the box. I am quite new to JS in general and very new to feathers, so probably have missed something very obvious. In the code below the TradeService.find always throws a failed promise.

I am inside a non-ejected CRA with mobx, but I don't think that is a problem. I have been watching tutorials and reading stuff.

I have a feathers.js file

```
    import io from "@feathersjs/socketio-client";
    import feathers from "@feathersjs/client";

    const socket = io("http://localhost:3030");

    const client = feathers().configure(feathers.socketio(socket));

    const TradeService = client.service("trades");

    export { client, TradeService };
```

Then the main file where it all goes wrong looks like this

```
import { TradeService } from "../../feathers";

@observer
export default class HeadlineReportPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      trades: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchFromServer();
  }

  fetchFromServer = async () => {
    console.log("tradeService: " + TradeService);
    await TradeService.find({
      query: {
        $limit: 0
      }
    })
      .then(res => {
        console.log("in then");
        console.log("total is " + res.total);
        setState({ trades: res.data });
      })
      .catch(res => console.log("Failed promise :" + res));
  };
```

I stole most of this code from examples online, so was expecting it to just get to the 'then', but it goes to the catch every time. I have tried with and without the async/await.

Comment: why you use to find in documentation I didn't find anywhere using find a method ?

Comment: Its part of the feathersjs service API

Comment: What's the error? If you enabled authentication, you have to authenticate first as shown in the Feathers frontend guide (this applies to any frontend framework).

Comment: There is no authentication enabled. The error is just a failed promise 

Failed promise: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '(_this$connection3 = _this.connection)[_this.method].apply')

I feel like its a scope issue with the connection... but i have followed the examples so am a bit confused.